# How do i make this Taxonomy term code work?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Hi i have this code below in my header file

```
<?php
if ( ! is_home() ) {

if ( get_post_type() == 'pretty-little-liars' ) {
    echo '<div id="headerimg"><img  src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/liars.png"></div>';
}
if ( get_post_type() == 'revenge' ) {
    echo '<div id="headerimg"><img  src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/revenge.png"></div>';
}
if ( is_tax( 'series', 'pretty-little-liars' ) ) $stylesheet_uri = $stylesheet_dir_uri . 'http://www.tv-cafe.com/wp-content/themes/tvcafe/posttypecss/style-pll.css';
}
?>
```

The first three "if" lines calls for a different header image which works properly, but the fourth "if" line i was trying to call for a different stylesheet for a Taxonomy term.

I have a post type entitled gallery, and under the gallery post type i have the Taxonomy "Series" and one of the terms happens to be "pretty-little-liars".

Here is what i want. Whenever a user click on a gallery post and it's under the Taxonomy Term "pretty-little-liars" I want it to have a different background image. The above code doesn't work for the taxonomy so what am i doing wrong or how do i fix this, suggestions anyone? I would really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

[is_tax()](http://queryposts.com/function/is_tax/) is a check for taxonomy archive page and as I understand you want this for individual posts. The function to use would be [has_term()](http://queryposts.com/function/has_term/):

```
if ( has_term( 'pretty-little-liars', 'series' ) )
```

Also it's good practice to enqueue style properly via [wp_enqueue_style()](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_enqueue_style/).

Comment: Thanks, you i just tried that but the styleshett still didn't change, here is what i have, is there anything else that needs to change `<?php if ( has_term( 'pretty-little-liars', 'series' ) ) $stylesheet_uri = $stylesheet_dir_uri . 'http://www.tv-cafe.com/wp-content/themes/tvcafe/posttypecss/style-pll.css';
} ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work thank goodness, here is the code.

```
<?php
if ( ! is_home() ) {

if ( get_post_type() == 'pretty-little-liars' ) {
    echo '<div id="headerimg"><img  src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/liars.png"></div>';
}
if ( get_post_type() == 'revenge' ) {
    echo '<div id="headerimg"><img  src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/revenge.png"></div>';
}
if( has_term( 'pretty-little-liars', 'series' ) ) {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tv-cafe.com/wp-content/themes/tvcafe/posttypecss/style-pll.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />', '<div id="headerimg"><img  src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/liars.png"></div>';

}
}
?>
```